# Webpack can't find Entry Module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I migrated from Webpack 1 to Webpack 2 and now when I run Webpack on my project I get this error:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/app.js' in '/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app'
resolve './src/app.js' in '/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app'
 using description file: /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/package.json (relative path: ./app)
   Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/package.json (relative path: ./app)
    using description file: /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/package.json (relative path: ./app/src/app.js)
      as directory
        /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/src/app.js doesn't exist
     no extension
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/src/app.js doesn't exist
     *
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/src/app.js* doesn't exist
     .js
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/src/app.js.js doesn't exist
     .jsx
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/src/app.js.jsx doesn't exist
     .json
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/src/app.js.json doesn't exist
```

My package.json is:

```
{
 "name": "AAA",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "dev": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot --inline --history-api-fallback"
 },

 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
   "eslint": "^3.13.1",
   "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.0.0",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.2",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
   "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
   "react-hot-loader": "^3.10.10",
   "react-router": "^3.0.2",
   "webpack": "^2.4.1",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.5.4",
   "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
   "react-hot-loader": "^3.10.10"
 },
}
```

this is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",

  entry: {
    app: "./src/app.js",
    javascript: "./js/app.js",
    html: "./index.html",
  },

  output: {
    //output.path: "[name].js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "[name].js"
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: { 'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount' },
    extensions: [ '*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules:[__dirname, './app/js', 'node_modules'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
        ],
        loaders: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: ["file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"],
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

I'm confused on how Webpack 2 should be set up and it has given me some problems so it might just be that my webpack config file has errors. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured [`context`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context) to be `./app/`. Webpack resolves everything that is used in the config as if you were in the `./app/` directory. As shown by the error, it looks for the file `./app/src/app.js`, which doesn't exist.

You either need to change / remove the `context` option (it defaults to the current directory) or you have to adjust the paths of the entry points.

Comment: Stupid mistake!lol..fixed it by changing App to `app: "./js/app.js",` which is my directory. D'oh!